.NET MAUI Windows Bluetooth works in debugger but not packaged app
I'm finalizing a Xamarin to Maui port of an app that utilizes Bluetooth.  This post is specific to the Windows version of the app. Bluetooth works when debugging with Visual Studio - my app is able to see and connect to Bluetooth devices. When I publish the app for sideloading, and install it, the app is not able to access bluetooth services - it is like it is missing permissions. The problem is not related to Debug/Release builds. Bluetooth works when running the app within Visual Studio in either debug or release. Neither Debug/Release work when published.
I've declared the appropriate  in the package.appxmanifest:
<DeviceCapability Name="radios"/>
<DeviceCapability Name="bluetooth"/>

Am I missing something?
Note: I've submitted this as a maui bug as everything is pointing that direction right now.  The bug report has a link to a sample project that demonstrates the issue.
https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/21626

Feel free to post an answer below if you have solved this issue!

When I published my app I had created an x86 publishing profile because that is what I had always used with the Xamarin version of my app.  However, that doesn't seem to work for some reason.
When I created an x64 publishing profile, the resulting build worked fine.
It seems to me that this is a bug.  Shouldn't an x86 build be able to run fine?
